# I can't create Enum columns with postgresql & sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the below code created in flask and sqlalchemy to create an Enum column in the postgresql database, despite I already gave it a name I still receive the following error.

```
class ReportModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reports'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cause = db.Column(db.Enum('Abuse', 'Discrimination', 'Fraud', name='cause'), nullable=False)
```

the error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py", line 2340, in format_type
   raise exc.CompileError("PostgreSQL ENUM type requires a name.")
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: PostgreSQL ENUM type requires a name.
```

any ideas how to solve it please?
I already tried every possible way but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name:

```
 cause = db.Column('cause', db.Enum('Abuse', 'Discrimination', 'Fraud', name='cause'), nullable=False)
```

Comment: thank you so much for that.
now I want when I send the postman request, to include INT 0,1,2 to return the corresponding value in this enum, but it gives me sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input value for enum

how to solve it please ?